# Drupal 7 - Redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, drupal-7

I transformed my "old school" php website into a Drupal website. However, I can't get the  Redirect 301 rules to work for the old URLs.

I placed the following Redirect rule in the .htaccess in the root.

```
RewriteRule ^recept_details.php?id=13 http://www.kooknet.be/recepten/nagerecht/tiramisu [R=301,L]
```

I did this after the following code in the .htaccess file:

```
  # RewriteBase /
```

The result is that I get redirected to a 404 page. I saw that there is a path_redirect module, but not yet available in Drupal 7.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't guess as to why your .htacccess redirect isn't redirecting, but there is a [Redirect module](http://drupal.org/project/redirect) for Drupal 7.